# Random bgColor: is it possible for colour to be different for every click?

Tags: javascript

I have a background that changes colour randomly every time a button is clicked. Is it possible to ensure that the colour is different upon every click (avoiding the possibility that the same colour is generated 2-3 times in a row)? Source code for the .js file is below (HTML is basically just the button).

```
var bgcolorlist, btn;
function newColor() {
    bgcolorlist = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolorlist;
}
function initAll() {
    btn = document.getElementById('click1');
    btn.addEventListener('click', newColor, false);
}
initAll();
```

Comment: Add colors to an array, if it is in the array, generate a new one.

Comment: Might I ask, what the purpose of `document.body.style.backgroundColor` is in `initAll()`?

Comment: What is your the definition / threshold  for "the same color".  Given that simply taking an arbitrary random color has 1 in 16 million chance of repeating I feel you might be after ensuring that the colors are appreciably different.

Comment: If the color differs minimal as in #FF0000 and #FF0001 it will be a different color per se, but you won't see a difference. So you might want to prevent _similar_ colors to reappear. That will invalidate solutions like storing previous colors for comparison. So maybe you have to check each color channel to differ at least by 20 or so from previous colors.

Comment: @Zenyal  Thanks for picking up on the unnecessary line. I've removed it & it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var bgcolorlist, btn;
var colorList = [];
function newColor() {
  bgcolorlist = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  while(colorList.indexOf(bgcolorlist) != -1){
    bgcolorlist = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  }
  colorList.push(bgcolorlist);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolorlist;
}
function initAll() {
  btn = document.getElementById('click1');
  btn.addEventListener('click', newColor, false);
}
initAll();
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution given. May I know the purpose of adding `document.body.style.backgroundColor;` inside the function `initAll` ?

Comment: @GopinathShiva typo whoops :)

Comment: @Gopinath Shiva - thanks, the extra line is now removed.

Comment: @A.J. Thank you for the solution. It still seems to have the same colour twice in a row occasionally but as previous comments suggest, perhaps it's just a very minimal shade change. Does the while loop ensure the colour is different from the last-generated colour, or..? Thanks again.

Comment: It makes sure that the same rgb values are not repeated; however, similar shades, such as `rgb(55, 66, 77)` and `rgb(56, 67, 78)` will be counted as different even though they are visually identical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with constant-time lookup into the set of previously generated colors. There would be significant speed improvements using this method over the used color array if the color array got larger.

```
var usedColors = {};
function randomColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
}
function unusedColor() {
  var color;
  while ((color = randomColor()) in usedColors);
  usedColors[color] = true;
  return '#' + color;
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = unusedColor();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This strategy compares each channel (new and old) and ensures that on a channel by channel basis there is at least a minimum change (threshold)

```js
function getChannelColor(color, threshold){
  var _new = 0;
  var _tooCloseMin = color - threshold;
  var _tooCloseMax = color + threshold;

  do { _new = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256); }
  while (_tooCloseMin < _new && _new < _tooCloseMax);

  return _new;
}

setInterval(function(){
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  var threshold = 5;

  var prevRGB = getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor.match(/\d+/g);
  var prevR = parseInt(prevRGB[0]);
  var prevG = parseInt(prevRGB[1]);
  var prevB = parseInt(prevRGB[2]);

  var newR = getChannelColor(prevR, threshold);
  var newG = getChannelColor(prevG, threshold);
  var newB = getChannelColor(prevB, threshold);
  
  target.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + newR + ", " + newG + ", " + newB + ")";
}, 1000);
```

```css
#target{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```